# Program closes abruptly after (input<- Console.ReadLine() |>int) line before showing variables F#

Tags: f#

Just a quick snippet of the function in which the error occurs

```
let fightmon(a: Monster) (b: User) = 
    let textoftype = showtype a.dType
    let mmaxhealth = a.hVal
    let mutable mhealth = a.hVal
    let mutable mdam = a.dVal
    let mutable mtype = a.dType
    let mutable uhealth = b.hVal
    let mutable uarm = b.Arm.aVal
    let mutable udam = b.Weap.dVal
    let mutable utype = b.Arm.dType
    printf "The %s appears infront of you, seems to be a %s type \n " a.name textoftype
    printf "%s" a.info
    while mhealth>0.9 || uhealth>0.9 do
        let mutable input =0
        while input <> 1 || input<> 2 do
            printf "Attack with 1, enter inventory with 2 "
            input <- Console.ReadLine() |>int
            printf "input read"
            if input<>1 || input<>2 then 
                printf "The option you selected is not applicable \n"
```

The program prints the first 3 printf statements , but seems to stop at the

```
input<- Console.ReadLine() |>int
```

before giving an output like so

```
    type Armour =
  {name: string;
   aVal: float;
   dType: DamType;
   info: string;
   iSpace: int;
   hidden: bool;}
type Weapon =
  {name: string;
   dVal: float;
```

etc

Is the issue within this snippet of code or elsewhere, because this also occurs in my other functions that use the input<-Console.Readline() |>int line

Comment: Are you sure it stops, and isn't just waiting for your input? If using fsi, it tends to first execute your function (including print statements),and then print out all the types and variables you've defined after. If the program stops, are you getting some error?

Comment: It gets to the part in which the user is asked to enter 1 or 2, then it prints all types and variables. After which if I enter 1 or 2, nothing occurs

Comment: just a side note: as written the expression `input<>1 || input<>2` is always `true` regardless of the value of `input`, i.e. useless; change it to `input<>1 && input<>2` to implement the intention.

Comment: Are you pressing the Enter key after entering the 1 or 2? The Enter key will complete the line that you are trying to read.